# Is it correct to use two adjectives before the phrase "as always"?

Tags: phrase-usage, grammatical-number

I put the caption "Outspoken and candid as always" on a video I posted for Riz Ahmad in the Trevor Noah show. But I'm not sure if it sounds correct because I have always heard sentences where it's always "something as always" not "something and something as always". Should I remove one of the adjectives? Or is it fine?

This is the caption: "Outspoken and candid as always."

Answer (score 1):

It's OK. You may use multiple adjectives before such phrases as 'as always', 'as never before', etc.

> Beautiful, intelligent, and confident as always, Mary impressed all of
>   the guests at the dinner.